# How do you use Lumberjack logging in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoalumberjack

I'm in the process of converting an Objective-C file which uses Lumberjack Logging into  Swift. It seems to be mostly working, except for the part where I declare `ddloglevel`.

The Objective-C way to do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#endif
```

The Swift way:

```
#if DEBUG
let ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#else
let ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#endif
```

Except I'm this compile time error:  `Use of unresolved identifier 'LOG_LEVEL_INFO'`

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the library source, `LOG_LEVEL_INFO` and `LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` are `#define` macros, which Swift does not automatically import. Swift only sees `const`'s.

However, I think that your approach as a whole might not make sense - it looks like you're trying to assign a value to the global Objective-C constant `ddLogLevel`. Swift's `let` is not going to do that for you - it's a completely different namespace. This is on top of not being able to use Objective-C macros in Swift.

Your best bet is to leave an Objective-C file in your project (called, say, `LoggingConfig.m` that just contains:

```
#import "DDLog.h"

#ifdef DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#endif
```

The library you're using relies heavily on Objective-C features, so best to just use Objective-C to configure it.

**Edit**: Looking at this library in more detail (I'd never heard of it before), using CocoaLumberjack at all in Swift is probably not going to work out, as its primary API is a preprocessor macro named `DDLog`. I don't think it's a good match.

Comment: Yes, I am importing `DDLog.h` and `DDTTYLogger.h` and `DDLog.h` declares the `LOG_LEVEL`s.

Answer (score 8):

You can use workaround. Instead of setting logLevel globally (possible only in Objective-C), you could set logging level to all Loggers explicitly.
Example:

```
class LoggerFactory {
#if DEBUG
  static let defaultLogLevel: DDLogLevel = DDLogLevel.All
#else
  static let defaultLogLevel: DDLogLevel = DDLogLevel.Info
#endif

static func initLogging() {
  DDLog.addLogger(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance(), withLevel: defaultLogLevel)
  DDLog.addLogger(DDASLLogger.sharedInstance(), withLevel: defaultLogLevel)
}
```